# Redirect request based on parameter on GCP

Tags: redirect, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I've a small demo app which is a key-value store. I've uploaded this to GCP and I was wondering if I could redirect requests to appropriate shards. What I'm trying to do is something like this:

[image: scheme]

Although GCP's Load Balancer has URL Maps and path rules, it's mostly redirecting based on endpoint. For example for reaching a video content; `v1/hd/{videoId}` would redirect to HD video service and `v1/uhd/{videoId}` would redirect to UHD video service. In my case this does not solve my problem. I'd like Load Balancer to detect the parameter's first character, maybe a Regex like this `^([A-M]|[a-m])` or something along those lines, and if the parameter starts with a character from A to M it should redirect to service 1.

Is this something reasonable? If so, possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url maps path matcher **does not** support conditions or regex.

As quoted from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#pm-constraints), Path matcher has some constraints:

> A path rule can only include a wildcard character (*) after a forward slash character (/). For example, /videos/* and /videos/hd/* are valid for path rules, but /videos* and /videos/hd* are not.

> Path rules do not use regular expression or substring matching. For example, path rules for either /videos/hd or /videos/hd/* do not apply to a URL with the path /video/hd-abcd. However, a path rule for /video/* does apply to that path.

> Path matchers (and URL maps in general) do not offer features that function like Apache LocationMatch directives. If you have an application that generates dynamic URL paths that have a common prefix, such as /videos/hd-abcd and /videos/hd-pqrs, and you need to send requests made to those paths to different backend services, you might not be able to do that with a URL map. For simple cases containing only a few possible dynamic URLs, you might be able to create a path matcher with a limited set of path rules. For more complex cases, you need to do path-based regular expression matching on your backends.

---

What you are looking for can be achieved by setting up `Nginx` or `Apache` webservers as the only backend for your `LoadBalancer` and configuring this backend to route requests with *conditions* and/or *regex* to your services.

PS: [If is Evil... when used in location context](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)